# Is Memory increase create difference in output or behavior of java application?

Tags: java

I have created one java-swing application. 
The application runs perfectly runs perfect on my pc.
But it doesn't run perfectly on client pc.
I had increase my Virtual Memory, earlier on my pc.
So my question is..

**Is changing memory limit, effect or change application behavior?**

Is there anything that change the behavior of java application? bcz same application runs perfectly on my pc and same application does not running perfectly on client pc?
and there is no problem in code, i have checked three times.

**EDIT:**
This is one [screen shot](http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3332/4614654528_d2ba5815ce.jpg) of my application, if u see in the screen shot there is one table in which there are many images in it. 
Now on my pc i don't see any double images in that table.
But on client pc, i am seeing double images in that table but if u click on one of the images then after clicking , the image which is showing earlier changed.
now then i take database and all the images from client pc and then i tried to run the same application on my pc with same data which is also their on client machine.

But now there is no double images coming in that table on my pc.

i "increase my virtual memory"  means changing the heap size of virtual memory of jvm by adding...

```
java -Xmx512m
```

Comment: How exactly is it "not running perfectly"?

Comment: And what exactly do you mean with "increase my Virtual Memory"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Obviously, if you app runs into `OutOfMemoryError`, then [increasing the maximum heap size](http://www.informix-zone.com/node/46) can fix it.
- Faulty (on the hardware level) memory can cause Java programs to crash. This can be diagnosed by using a [memtest](http://www.memtest86.com/) tool
- Sometimes, [Swing gets at odds with hardware graphics acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591291/button-text-disappearing-with-4gb-ram-and-ibm-java-1-5), especially with onboard graphics adpaters that share main memory. This can be fixed either by reducing hardware acceleration in Windows, or getting new drivers.

Comment: see my editable question for more information on my question.

Comment: @Nitz: the errors you describe might indicate a problem as in my 3rd bullet point. Try deactivating hardware accel in the extended display settings. Or it could be caused by errors in your code being exposed by a different Java version. Try running with exactly the same Java version on both machines.

Comment: yes i agree, this problem may be with graphics..
but we can't make that kind of change in the client machine,
they won't like that thing.
so is their any solution for this?

Comment: @Nitz: none except updating to the most recent grapfics driver and JRE, and hoping that those contain a fix.

Comment: my assumption was right...
bcz ImageIO was loading images,
it require more memory,
as soon as increase memory heap size,
then all my images are start working and now there r no double image rendering problem......

Answer (score 2):

It's possible more memory to help. To optimize anything for better performance/scaling/size, you first need to understand the problem.

Examine how much memory your application uses - if you're on windows you can start by looking at it with task explorer. If the amount of memory used is a significant portion of the amount of memory your pc has, then adding more memory may well speed things up. Other things can affect performance such as hard disk speed and number of cpu's. You could add more memory, but find it's the hard disk speed that is the problem.

What kind of things does your program do. Does it work with files or large data-sets?

You haven't said how it doesn't run perfectly on the client's pc. Is it slow, or does it crash?

Answer (score 2):

Changes in the amount of memory and thus possibly in the amount of swapping necessary to provide memory to all applications can change the timing of your program.

If your program is susceptible to timing changes (i.e. if it is timing-dependent or only works in "best-case" timing), then those timing changes can influence the behaviour of your application.

Additionally restricted memory constraints can lead to more frequent garbage collection which also change the timing and can have an additional influence if you use any kinds of weak or soft references in your application.

Comment: see my editable question for more information on my question.

Answer (score 0):

You must check if the problem is with memory. Use ProcessManager or other similar program to check how your program use memory from OS point of view. You can use `jconsole` to check, how it looks from Java perspective.

Run your application with JDK and add to its invocation:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9876 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Then run `jconsole` and watch your app.